# Pass a parameter value to a Dataset Parameter in SSRS 2008

Tags: xml, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing, caml

I have a dataset with a parameter as which is passed to a query as shown below.

[image]

The issue here is DataSet parameter `queryOptions` does not accept the value from the Report Parameter `Date`.

If i hardcode any value e.g `<CalendarDate> 08/11/2012 </CalendarDate>` instead of `<CalendarDate> = Parameters!Date.Value </CalendarDate>` the report works fine.

What wrong am i doing while passing parameter.

I even created another Dataset Parameter named `Date` and assigned Parameter Value `[@Date]` even that did not work.

**Note**: Parameter `Date` is of type `DateTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got this working!

1. I created a new Parameters in the Parameters folder as `Date` and `queryOptions`.So basically `queryOptions` is everything that i want to use as a query.
2. Then another `queryOption` parameter is created under **Dataset Properties>>Parameters**.
3. Set value of  `queryOptions`(Step 2) to `[queryOptions]`(Step 1).

Comment: Hi @ishan it looks like you found a solution to this but I must admit I don't understand your answer.  Could you clarify, perhaps provide the same screenshots as you took for your question to show what it looks like now?  Would really appreciate it as I'm struggling with the same problem and can't seem to decide what you're saying here sorry!  Thanks!

Comment: @ebooyens sorry for that but yes I think i did not put it properly. I worked on this requirement almost 3 years back and i don't have the setup to provide screenshot. What you need to do is, the Parameters itself should form the 'queryOptions' for you and then just set the Parameters you created to the "Parameters of DataSet".

Comment: edited my answer. hope it helps. let me know if you need any further explanation on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the dynamic expression under your parameter value. Something like following expression:

```
    =”<QueryOptions><CalendarDate> = “&Parameters!Date.Value.Tostring(“MM/dd/yyyy”) &”</CalendarDate></QueryOptions>”
```